# Calling asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe across different event loops

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, python-asyncio, event-loop

I have a class inside a microservice that looks like this:

```
import asyncio
import threading

class A:
   def __init__(self):
      self.state = []
      self._flush_thread = self._start_flush()
      self.tasks = set()

   def _start_flush(self):
       threading.Thread(target=self._submit_flush).start()

   def _submit_flush(self):
       self._thread_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
       self._thread_loop.run_until_complete(self.flush_state()) # 

   async def regular_func(self):
      
      # This function is called on an event loop that is managed by asyncio.run()
      # process self.state, fire and forget next func
      task = asyncio.create_task(B.process_inputs(self.state)) # Should call process_inputs in the main thread event loop
      self.tasks.add(task)
      task.add_done_callback(self.tasks.discard)
      pass

   async def flush_state(self):
    # flush out self.state at regular intervals, to next func
    while True:
       # flush state 
       asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(B.process_inputs(self.state), self._thread_loop) # Calls process_inputs in the new thread event loop
       await asyncio.sleep(10)
    pass

class B:
   @staticmethod
   async def process_inputs(self, inputs):
       # process
```

On these two threads, I have two separate event loops to avoid any other async functions in the main event loop from blocking other asyncio functions from running.

I see that `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` is [thread safe when submitting to a given event loop.](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) Is `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(B.process_inputs())` called between different event loops still threadsafe?

Edit:
`process_inputs` uploads the state to an object store and calls an external API using the state we passed in.

Comment: Without knowing what "process_inputs" actually does and returns, there is no answer. The call `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(B.process_inputs())` executes "process_inputs" in the calling thread and expects that it returns a coroutine for another loop to execute.

Comment: `process_inputs` uploads the state to an object store and calls an external API using the state we passed in. Does that help?

Comment: If it doesn't return a coroutine, it makes no sense to wrap it in a call of "asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe".

Comment: I suspect you are misreading the documentation.  When it says "submit a coroutine to 'THE' given event loop", it is referring to the specific event loop that is passed as the second argument to the function.  In your code you don't have a second argument at all, so that is an error.  And as @Michael Butscher points out, the first argument isn't a coroutine, so that's another error.  FYI, there can be at most one event loop per thread, so asking another loop to run the coroutine always implies execution of the coroutine by another thread.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Thank you for correcting my mistakes, you are right. I went ahead and corrected them in the code. Also added `run_coroutine_threadsafe` where I wanted to call and passed in the loop. My question is, we have two calls of process_inputs in two different event loops in two different threads, both of which send self.state as input for `process_inputs`. Are there any thread safety issues when making such calls and accessing the same state between different event loops even when using `run_coroutine_threadsafe`

Comment: There are thread safety issues any time you have more than one thread, since they can preempt each other at any time.  You may need to protect certain data structures with Lock or Condition objects.  Asyncio does not cause any new thread safety problems, at least none that I'm aware of.  It doesn't solve any existing thread problems either.  There is no problem mixing asyncio and threading in the same program, as long as you are careful about what functions can be run in what context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is that `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` does not protect us from any thread safety issues across different event loops. We need to implement locks to protect any shared states while they are being modified. Credits to @Paul Cornelius for the reply.

Answer (score -1):

"*The run_coroutine_threadsafe() function allows a coroutine to be run in an asyncio program from another thread.*"
check out : [Example of Running a Coroutine From Another Thread](https://superfastpython.com/asyncio-run_coroutine_threadsafe/)

Comment: The key is different event_loops.